# Simple log4j configuration

Tags: java, log4j

I am using the following to enable debug information

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

To be honest, I copy above from somewhere else. I am not sure what's the CA mean here?

Answer (score 0):

it is Console Appender.
ConsoleAppender appends log events to System.out or System.err using a layout specified by the user. The default target is System.out.

Answer (score 0):

It's ConsoleAppender, but the name is not important as long as it's consistent.

For example

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, BLAH
log4j.appender.BLAH=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
```